# Neo4j - To compare two nodes properties with apoc.text.phonetic

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Within a Graph of **Persons** some of the nodes are connected with a `SAME_AS` relationship.

```
(p1:{name:'m.Verena von Habsburg-Laufenburg'})-[SAME_AS]-(p1:{name:'2m: 9.2.1354 Verena von Habsburg-Laufenburg'})
```

In the first example these persons are really the same but we have other example as:

```
(p1:{name:'m.Gf Antal Pejácsevich de Verõcze (+1838)'})-[SAME_AS]-(p2: {name:'2m: Budapest 5.7.1880 Gf Arthur Pejácsevich de Verõcze'})
```

Is there a chance to find a decision with apoc.text.phonetic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can judge by yourself.

### Your first example

```
WITH [
    "m.Verena von Habsburg-Laufenburg",
    "2m: 9.2.1354 Verena von Habsburg-Laufenburg"
] AS texts
UNWIND texts AS text
CALL apoc.text.phonetic(text) YIELD value
RETURN text, value
```

Results are the same :

```
text                                            value
"m.Verena von Habsburg-Laufenburg"              "M000V650V500H121L151"
"2m: 9.2.1354 Verena von Habsburg-Laufenburg"   "M000V650V500H121L151"
```

### Your second example

```
WITH [
    "m.Gf Antal Pejácsevich de Verõcze (+1838)",
    "2m: Budapest 5.7.1880 Gf Arthur Pejácsevich de Verõcze"
] AS texts
UNWIND texts AS text
CALL apoc.text.phonetic(text) YIELD value
RETURN text, value
```

Results are not the same :

```
text                                                        value
"m.Gf Antal Pejácsevich de Verõcze (+1838)"                 "M000G100A534P200C120D000V600C000"
"2m: Budapest 5.7.1880 Gf Arthur Pejácsevich de Verõcze"    "M000B312G100A636P200C120D000V600C000"
```

### Conclusion

It works for this example, but I'm not sure you can put it as a generic rule. Data lineage is complexe to achieve and you don't have any guaranty to be sure at 100%.
But definitively, `apoc.text.phonetic` can helps you to achieve your goal.

### Update

Your query should be like this :

```
MATCH (n1:Person)-[r:SAME_AS]->(n2:Person)
CALL apoc.text.phonetic(n1.name) YIELD value AS n1Phonetic
CALL apoc.text.phonetic(n2.name) YIELD value AS n2Phonetic
WHERE n1Phonetic = n2Phonetic
WITH r
    SET r.samePhonetic=true
```

Here I set the property `samePhonetic` to `true` if the phonetics are the same.

Moreover, there is an other procedure called `apoc.text.phoneticDelta` that can helps you to do this. With it you can defined a threshold, or directly store the delta as a property of your relationship like that :

```
MATCH (n1:Person)-[r:SAME_AS]->(n2:Person)
CALL apoc.text.phoneticDelta(n1.name, n2.name) YIELD delta
WITH r, delta
    SET r.phoneticDelta=delta
```

A score of 4 means that your two strings are very similar. 
A score of 0 means that your two strings are very different.

Comment: Thanks. I used your query and built a generic one for my database:

`MATCH (n1:Person)-[:SAME_AS]-(n2:Person)
WITH COLLECT([n1.name, n2.name]) AS texts
UNWIND texts AS text
CALL apoc.text.phonetic(text) YIELD value
RETURN text, value`

Is there a way to mark the SAME_AS-edge it values are equal ?